# Segmentation fault every third running my program, using mallloc

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am getting a segmentation fault almost every third time, and I am trying to understand why. I think the reason for it is using `malloc()` and `free()` wrong. I have to read the user stdin and then save it in an array using malloc. This part was working, until somehow the errors started happening.

My code:

```
char *Input() {
    char user_input;
    int length;

    char *buffer = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

    while (((user_input = getchar(stdin)) != EOF) && (user_input != '\n')) {
        buffer[length] = user_input;
        length++;
        char *buffer_new = realloc(buffer, length + 2);
        if (buffer_new != NULL) {
            buffer = buffer_new;
        } else {
            free(buffer);
            printf("Error.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    buffer[length] = '\0'; 

    if (strlen(buffer) > 200) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

I am not really sure where my mistake is or why the error happens. Here is how I call the function:

```
int main() {
    char *input = Input();

    if (input == 1)
        return 1;
    if (input == 2)
        return 2;

    free(*input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remember, `EOF` will only work if it is compared against an `int`, `long`, or `long long`.  change your `user_input` to type `int` instead of `char`.  also, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: You should initialize length and use it to do your allocations.

Comment: `free(*input);` is wrong, you free a pointer, not what it points to. Returning 1 from a function that says it will return a pointer is also incorrect. If you wish to indicate an error you'd likely want to return a NULL pointer.

Comment: Also next time, don't forget to share your error message with us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary problem I see is, in your code for `Input()` function, `length` is a local variable with automatic storage duration and not initialized explicitly. So, it contains indeterminate value. Thus, the statement

```
 buffer[length] = user_input;
```

is accessing invalid memory address. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have to explicitly initialize the `length` to `0`.

After that, know that [`getchar()` returns an `int`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-getchar/), and a value like `EOF` cannot fit into a `char`. You need to change the `user_input` to `int`.

Also, in the `main()`, you have defined `input` as a pointer,

```
char* input = Input();
```

but, you are comparing it against an `int` value, this is most likely not what you want.

You should be comparing against the value stored in the pointer, something like

```
if (*input == 1)
    return 1;
if (*input == 2)
    return 2;
```

and finally, you pass the pointer to `free()`, not the content, so change

```
 free(*input);
```

to

```
 free(input);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it.

Comment: The segmentation fault is not accuring so often but still some times. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign any value to `length`, it can be any value. If you're lucky, that won't overflow when using `buffer[length]`, but don't count on luck. initialise it. `int length = 0;`